# Extract all contents inside brackets (including the brackets) in a data frame column

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have this column of data in a `DataFrame` (just shown here in a `CSV` file):

[image]

What I am trying to do is extract all the data within the brackets and also include the brackets so each row looks something like this

```py
[GO:0005524],[GO:0000287],[GO:0004709],[GO:0004674],etc...
```

This is the code I have so far but I always end up with a blank column:

```py
df['go_molecular_function'] = df['go_molecular_function'].str.extract(r"\((A-Za-z+)\)", expand=False)
```

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out I used this code

```
df['go_molecular_function'] = df['go_molecular_function'].str.findall(r"(?<=\[)([^]]+)(?=\])")
```

[image: and ended up with this which I am happy with]